# Placing a Union query in the resultset

Tags: sql, eclipse, jsp, jdbc

Can anybody suggest if there are any rules to place a union query in jdbc resultset?
i have a union query in database where i got the output...but when i tried to place the same Union query in resultset ,

> am getting an error:ASA Error -131: Syntax error near 'unionselect'
>   on line ...

Can anyone suggest me as where i went wrong...

The query in jsp page is as follows.....

```
String QueryString = 

"select CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),[startdatetime],111) AS [year-month],nm.nameLine1 as CompanyName, sum(datediff(hour, startdatetime, enddatetime)) as total" 
+" from servicerequestworklog as srl"
+" inner join ServiceRequest sr on srl.ServiceRequestId = sr.ServiceRequestId"
+" inner join Name nm on(sr.clientCustomerId = nm.customerId and nm.nameTypeId = 'OFIC')"
+" where (startdatetime >= '08-01-2011 00:00:00.000' and enddatetime <= '10-31-2011 00:00:00.000')"
+" group by CompanyName, [year-month]"
+"union" 
+"select CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),[startdatetime],111) AS [year-month], 'ZZTOTAL' as CompanyName, sum(datediff(hour, startdatetime, enddatetime)) as total"
+" from servicerequestworklog as srl"
+"inner join ServiceRequest sr on srl.ServiceRequestId = sr.ServiceRequestId"
+" where (startdatetime >= '08-01-2011 00:00:00.000' and enddatetime <= '10-31-2011 00:00:00.000')"
+" group by [year-month]"
+"order by CompanyName, [year-month]" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid these type of errors by using `PreparedStatement` (Parameterized query). I think you have to add space between `union` and `select` words.

Comment: Thanks alot!...my problem is solved...As u expected, its due to the spaces between Union AND SELECT...